# Find the frequency of rows from multiple joint tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this problem with SQL and I can't figure it out. 
Imagine that I have 3 tables as follows

```
   Names
   Nameid  name
   1       Starbucks Coffee
   2       Johns Restaurant
   3       Davids Restaurant

   user_likes
   userid   Nameid
   1        1
   2        1
   2        3

   user_visited
   userid   Nameid
   1        2
```

I want to find the places with the most number of (likes+visited). I also want to select all places not just those who have been liked or visited

I do:

```
 SELECT n.nameid, n.name , COUNT(f.nameid) AS freq
 FROM names AS n
 LEFT JOIN user_likes ON n.nameid=user_likes.nameid
 LEFT JOIN user_visited ON n.nameid=user_visited.nameid
 ORDER BY freq DESC
```

But it doesn't give me the total frequency. The problem is, if a place is both visited and liked, it is counted only once, while I want it to be counted twice.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a quick test and although I prefer Serge's solution, this one seemed to perform faster as the amount of items to join will be less:

```
SELECT n.nameId, n.name, coalesce(sum(likesCount), 0) totalCount FROM NAMES n
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT nameId, count(*) likesCount FROM user_likes
  GROUP BY nameId
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nameId, count(*) visitsCount FROM user_visited
  GROUP BY nameId
) s ON n.nameId = s.nameId
GROUP BY n.nameId
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

I'm assuming the following indexes:

```
alter table names add index(nameid);
alter table user_likes add index(nameid);
alter table user_visited add index(nameid);
```

Probably the OP can compare the efficiency of both queries with actual data and provide feedback.

Comment: I think if you already calculated counts in inner queries, you could replace UNION with JOIN (uniqueness of nameid would make it one-to-one) and then just return likesCount+visitsCount. Of course, with your nonnulling feature. Will it be faster, one join instead of one grouping? (You already tested, I presume you are able to do it quickly =)

Comment: Sorry, but I can not fully get the idea. At first sight I think there will never be unique nameId. Firstly, because it seems there is a compound key in `user_likes` and `user_visited`. Secondly because there are 2 different tables to get them from, so you could have the same nameId in both of them (even after grouping). Or probably I got lost in your idea (feel free to provide an answer with it)

Comment: That is my idea [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84330/6). I don't fully understand how you concluded what is faster, since that fiddle gives exec time from 0 to 26ms on same query, so it's quite random. There should be more data and a non-public server.

Comment: I compered the [fiddle with your answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84330/1) against the [fiddle with my answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84330/2) and noticed the execution plans were exactly the same but scanned less rows. Although I agree on the fact that it is required to be tested on an environment with real data (as I stated in my answer) I think it will be most likely that the non-group by solution would take more. The 3rd query you provided in your last comment also contains the double group by and, it seems to scan less rows. That one does seem to run faster. Add it to your answer.

Comment: Interesting, /2 and /6 options work with different execution plans but same total amount of scanned rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT n.name, t.nameid, COUNT(t.nameid) AS freq
FROM Names n
JOIN (
    SELECT nameid FROM user_likes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nameid FROM user_visited
) t
ON n.nameid = t.nameid
GROUP BY t.nameid ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it without SELECT within SELECT?

Comment: I came up with this:
 SELECT n.nameid, n.name , SUM((user_likes.userid>0)+(user_visited.userid>0) ) AS freq
 FROM names AS n
 LEFT JOIN user_likes ON n.nameid=user_likes.nameid
 LEFT JOIN user_visited ON n.nameid=user_visited.nameid
 ORDER BY freq DESC
The problem is, when one of user_likes or user_visited is not joined for a row, that sum returns NULL.

Comment: @friendq I don't think that it would give you what you need. Joins work each with each, so if you have for some name two records in user_likes and two records in user_visited, double joining will give you four rows. But anyway, problems with nulls are solved with using JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @MostyMostacho That depends. There may be a lot of boring places that nobody likes nor visits, so inner joining will play its role.

Answer (score 0):

Mosty, your usage of coalesce() gave me an idea and I came up with this:

```
  SELECT n.nameid, n.name , 
  SUM((IFNULL(user_likes.userid,0)>0)+(IFNULL(user_visited.userid,0)>0) ) AS freq
  FROM names AS n LEFT JOIN user_likes ON n.nameid=user_likes.nameid LEFT JOIN 
  user_visited ON n.nameid=user_visited.nameid ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Since my example here was a simplification of my problem (I have to join more than two tables to the main table) I'm reluctant to use SELECT inside SELECT, because I know it's not very efficient. Do you see any fundamental problem with my solution?

Comment: Ah, you were right, Sergio. "if you have for some name two records in user_likes and two records in user_visited, double joining will give you four rows. "

Comment: You always choose between memory and performance. Add a column freq to table Names, update it, and you won't need to compute anything. Or just merge both tables into one: `user_likes_visited (int nameid, int userid, int type)`, holding type=1 for like, type=2 for visit. Then grouping will work quickly on one indexed table.